# How can I make turtle recognise he is in a circle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Okay so I have a turtle that will randomly go to a coordinate on the map and draw a circle, that turtle will also go to the center of that circle.

My other turtle will go to where ever you click on the map.

How can I make python print 'You are in a circle' if you click inside of the circle that the first turtle has drawn?

What I have so far:

```
from turtle import *
from random import *

billy = Pen()
jim = Pen()
jim_x = randint(-300, 300)
jim_y = randint(-300, 300)

billy.speed('fastest')
jim.speed('fastest')

jim.penup()
jim.hideturtle()

jim.goto(jim_x, jim_y)

jim.color('dark red')
jim.begin_fill()
jim.circle(25)
jim.end_fill()

jim.goto(jim_x, (jim_y + 25))

print jim.xcor()
print jim.ycor()

def billyPos(x, y):
    billy.penup()
    billy.goto(x, y)
    if billy.position() is inside circle: #this is where i was gonna put the statment
        print 'you are in a circle'

onscreenclick(billyPos)
done()
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example:

```
if 25 > abs(billy.pos()-jim.pos()):
    print 'you are in a circle'
```